# Where i can find the kinetic reaction about the US20050281732A1 patent?

Tags: kinetic, reaction

I cant find anything on journal explain about the kinetic reaction beeten FeCl2 + H2SO4

Comment: I don’t think this is a question about patents. Can you edit it to make within scope?

Answer (score 0):

Normally technical questions are off topic on Ask Patents. However I, like you, have often tried to search for more information related to what I found in a patent document so I'm trying to address your question.

Patents (and the cited document is an application, the [associated patent is here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7097816B2/en?oq=US7097816B2)) are unlike academic publications. If the invention is by an academic researcher then there is every possibility the inventor may publish in a journal after the application is filed. However many, if not most, inventions are not by academics so publication in a technical journal is less likely. Each patent (or application) cites [some relevant prior art](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20050281732A1/en?oq=US20050281732A1#patentCitations) so you can start your searching with those. Otherwise I would try Google searching with the inventor's name and some applicable keywords. I google searched with the keywords: "Alexander Kehrmann" "ferrous sulfate heptahydrate" and found the [following results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Alexander%20Kehrmann%22%20%22ferrous%20sulfate%20heptahydrate%22&newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=KU7AY-rZKOi80PEPvuKqiAk&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY8BcOX0hVMEyx9-SyeUVASciPS7zHln4&ved=0ahUKEwiqkq3F0cL8AhVoHjQIHT6xCpEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22Alexander%20Kehrmann%22%20%22ferrous%20sulfate%20heptahydrate%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6BggAEBYQHjoJCAAQFhAeEPEEUABYq8cBYJ7PAWgBcAB4AIABxAGIAeQEkgEDNS4ymAEAoAEBoAEC&sclient=gws-wiz). A [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C48&q=%22Alexander%20Kehrmann%22%20%22ferrous%20sulfate%20heptahydrate%22&btnG=) with the same keywords found only two hits.